# Multiple Google Maps on Same Page from Mysql?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that a user inputs markers on a google map and it saves the center of map latitude and longitude, zoom and the latitude and longitude of the marker into MySQL. Next I'm trying to have a page that displays all the different maps a user has saved with the markers. I have searched and all I can find is how to display multiple markers on the same map or a set number of maps on the same page with a set lat and long.
Could anybody suggest where to start with this or a tutorial on this.

Here is the code I've started with that displays one google map with all the markers that have been entered. Not familiar with javascript, so need pointed in the right direction.
Thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[

    function load() {
    var latitude= <?php echo json_encode($maplat);?>;
    var longitude= <?php echo json_encode($maplon); ?>;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom:  <?php echo $mapzoom;?>,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
      var log = markers[i].getAttribute("log");

      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latit")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longit")));
      var html = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + log;

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,

      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

 </script>
```

Comment: I may not be getting what you're asking. You talk about saving center points for the maps. Do you want to show all the maps on the screen at one time, or do you want to have a way to access all these maps on a page? If you're trying to put all the markers on the map at once to show all the saved markers, why are you saving zoom and center point in the first place?

Comment: No. I'm trying to show all the maps on screen at one time. Right now it just shows the map of the last entry with all the markers. I'm trying to learn javascript. Hoping that then I could figure out where to start the loop for the map.